# Platform used for creating following video

Tags: premiere, video-editor

This may be a subjective question, but I'm not sure where else to ask, so apologies in advance!

I want to know the name of the software being used to make such purple, pink blocks as shown in the video below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely simply a presentation program. The best known is PowerPoint, but you can get one free using Libre Office https://www.libreoffice.org/ or some web-based like google docs.

Libre Office has two programs that can be suitable. Impress and Draw.

Comment: Thanks Rafael I COULD DO THAT IN Google Sheets

Answer (score -1):

I would do it in Adobe illustrator as it helps with lining up things